# Schedule a task in EC2 Auto Scaling Group

Tags: spring, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, autoscaling, spring-scheduled

I have multiple EC2s on an autoscaling group. They all run the same java application. In the application, I want to trigger a functionality every month. So, I have a function that uses Spring Schedule and runs every month. But, that function is run on every single EC2 instance in the autoscaling group while it must run only once. How should I  approach this issue? I am thinking of using services like Amazon SQS but they would have the same problem.

To be more specific on what I have tried, in one attempt the function puts a record with a key unique to this month on a database which is shared among all the ec2 instances. If the record for this month is already there, the put request is ignored. Now the problems transfer to the reading part? I have a function that reads the database and do the job. But that function is run by every single ec2 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting! You could put a configuration on *one* of the servers to trigger a monthly activity, but individual instances in an Auto Scaling group should be treated as identical, fragile systems that could be replaced during a month. So, there would be no guarantee that this specific server would be around in one month.

I would suggest you take a step back and look at the monthly event as something that is **triggered external to the servers**.

I'm going to assume that the cluster of servers is running a web application and there is a Load Balancer in front of the instances that distributes traffic amongst the instances. If so, "something" should send a request to the Load Balancer, and this would be forwarded to one of the instances for processing, just like any normal request.

This particular request would be to a URL used specifically trigger the monthly processing.

This leaves the question of what is the "something" that sends this particular request. For that, there are many options. A simple one would be:

- Configure **Amazon CloudWatch Events** to trigger a Lambda function based on a schedule
- The **AWS Lambda function** would send the HTTP request to the Load Balancer